# How can I save a word document (from Word Android app) to Google drive?

Tags: applications, google-drive, ms-office

There are options for OneDrive and Dropbox, but I can't save to my Google drive account, why?!

Comment: Open Google Drive app and upload the file manually by browsing to its location.

Comment: but that wouldn't sync the file?!

Comment: It will be synced.

Comment: To answer your question in the body, that's because it's Microsoft's app and they want you to use their services instead of Google's. Marketing strategy. The actual question has been addressed by @MANI.